# How to run all functions at once in shell script menu

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I unfortunately developed my script to be a little overly complex for my basic understanding. i currently added functions and a menu to run those functions but i have no idea how to add a property for running all functions. Im sorry if i lacking in the description, but id like essentially add the run all property in my menu without really ruining the functionality of the current menu scheme. thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/bash
# Linux host info script
# Matthew Morcaldi 2015
# DONUTS version 0.2.0 last update (2/24/2015)
# w00t be in r00t

# Config ------------------------------------------------
outfile="linux_info.txt"
#--------------------------------------------------------

#### uncomment (set -x) for debug 
# set -x 



outfile="linux_info.txt"


checkroot() {
    if [ $UID -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "User has insufficient privilege."
        exit 4
    fi
}



header() { 
    echo '' | tee -a $outfile
    echo '----------------------' | tee -a $outfile
    echo "[*] $title" | tee -a $outfile
    echo '----------------------' | tee -a $outfile
}

display_os() {
    title="Display_OS"
    header $title
    /bin/uname -r | tee -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t 1 | grep -i 'serial' | sed 's/^    *//' | tee -a $outfile
    cat /etc/*-release | tee -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t system -q | egrep -i 'Manufacturer: |Product|UUID' | \
    sed 's/^    *//' | tee -a $outfile
    /usr/bin/ipmitool bmc info | egrep -i 'Firmware revision' | tee  -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t bios -q | egrep -i 'version|vendor' | \
    sed 's/^    *//' | tee -a $outfile

}

display_mount() {
    title="Mount"
    header $title
    mount |column -t | tee -a $outfile
}

display_network_oob() {
    title="Drac-Info"
    header $title
    ipmitool lan print | egrep -i 'IP Address|MAC Address|Default Gateway IP|Subnet Mask' | tee -a $outfile
}

display_networking() {
    title="Networking"
    header $title
    ifconfig -a | tee -a $outfile
    arp -e | tee -a $outfile
}

display_bonding() {
    if [ -f /proc/net/bonding/bond0 -a -f /bin/netstat ] ; then
        title="Bonding"
        header $title
        cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        /bin/netstat -ni | column -t | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "Bond0 or netstat does not exist skipping"
    fi
}

display_switch_info() {
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/lldpctl ] ; then
        title="Switch-Port-Information"
        header $title
        lldpctl | egrep '(Interface|VLAN|PortDescr|SysName|ChassisID)' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "Switch file LLDPCTL does not exist skipping"
    fi
}

display_CPU_info() {
        title="CPU-Info"
        header $title
        cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep -i 'processor|vendor_id|model name|cpu MHz|physical id|siblings|core id|cpu cores' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        /usr/bin/lscpu | egrep -i 'Architecture|CPU op-mode|Hyper|virtualization|CPU ' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
}

show_disks_dell() {
    if [ -f /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 ] ; then
        title="Dell-Raid"
        header $title
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -PDList -aAll |  \
        egrep -i 'count|^Device Id: |firmware state' |  \
        grep -v 'Count: 0' | \
        perl -p -e 's/Firmware state: (.*)$/Firmware state: $1\n/' | tee -a $outfile
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LDInfo -Lall -aALL | \
        egrep -i 'virtual|cache|state|raid level|name|size|number' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "skipping Dell disk check"
     fi
}

show_battery_dell() {
    if [ -f /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 ]; then
        title="Dell-Battery"
        header $title
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpBbuCmd -GetBbuStatus -a0 | \
        egrep -i 'isSOHGood|Charger Status|Capacity|Relative|Charging' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "skipping Dell battery check"
    fi
}

show_disks_hp() {
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/hpacucli ]; then
        title="HP-Raid"
        header $title
        hpacucli ctrl all show config detail | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    else
        echo "skipping HP disk check"
    fi
}

show_battery_hp() {
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/hpacucli ]; then
        title="HP-Battery"
        header $title
        hpacucli ctrl all show status | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    else
        echo "skipping HP battery check"
    fi
}

show_sysprofile_dell() {
    if [ -f /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/syscfg ]; then
        title="BIOS power settings Dell"
        header $title
        /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/syscfg --SysProfile | tee -a $outfile
        /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/syscfg --ProcPwrPerf | tee -a $outfile
        /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/syscfg --logicproc | tee -a $outfile
        /opt/dell/toolkit/bin/syscfg --virtualization | tee -a $outfile

    else
        echo "skipping Dell power settings check"
    fi
}

show_sysprofile_HP() {
    if [ -f /opt/hp/conrep ]; then
        title="BIOS power settings HP"
        header $title
        cd /opt/hp/
        ./conrep -s -f output
        cd
        less /opt/hp/output | grep Hyperthreading | tee -a $outfile
        less /opt/hp/output | grep CPU_Virtualization | tee -a $outfile
        less /opt/hp/output | grep HP_Power_Profile | tee -a $outfile
        rm -f /opt/hp/output


    else
        echo "skipping HP power settings check"
    fi
}



display_dimms() {
        title="Memory"
        header $title
        cat /proc/meminfo|grep MemTotal | tee -a $outfile
        free -g | tee -a $outfile
        dmidecode -t Memory Device -q |egrep -i 'Size:|Type: D|Locator: D' | \
        perl -p -e 's/Type: (.*)$/Type: $1\n/' | tee -a $outfile


}

sel_list() {
    title="SEL"
    header $title
    ipmitool sel elist | tee -a $outfile
}

exit_script() {
    title="exit_script"
    header $title
    service ipmi stop
    exit 0

}

########## 


checkroot
echo 'Press [Enter] key to continue.'
read goforit
service ipmi start

while true
do 
echo "Menu: "

FUNCTION_COUNT=15
STUFFTODOFUNC=("display_os" "display_mount" "display_CPU_info" "display_dimms" "sel_list" "show_sysprofile_dell" "show_sysprofile_HP" "show_disks_hp" "show_battery_hp" "show_disks_dell" "show_battery_dell" "display_network_oob" "display_networking" "display_bonding" "display_switch_info" "exit_script" )
STUFFTODONAME=('Display_OS' 'Display_Mount_Info' 'Display_CPU_Info' 'Display_Memory' 'System_Event_List' 'Dell_BIOS_Power_Settings' 'HP_BIOS_Power_Settings' 'HP_RAID' 'HP_RAID_Battery' 'Dell_RAID' 'Dell_RAID_Battery' 'Display_Network_OOB' 'Display_Network' 'display_bonding' 'Display_Switch_Port_Information' 'exit' )
COUNT=0
for ITEM in ${STUFFTODONAME[*]}
do
  echo -n " ${COUNT}. ${ITEM}  " | tr '_' ' '
  COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
done
echo ""
echo -n "Please Select From Above.:"
read FUNCTION
echo ${STUFFTODONAME[FUNCTION]}
echo ""
${STUFFTODOFUNC[FUNCTION]}

    done
```

Comment: Write another function that just calls all these functions. Add it to the menu.

Comment: you're almost there `run_all() { f1; f2; f3; ...; }` Good luck.